# Difference in drawing on canvas when saved as .html and .php

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

[image: screenshot of canvas.php]When i drew on to canvas and saved it as .php file then it looks blurry than when saved as .html file. I dont understand why this is happening? canvas.html is very clear in comparison to canvas.php .

```
body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: green;
}
canvas {
position:absolute;
background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="500"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas'),
 ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.fillStyle="red";
 ctx.font="100px bold cursive";
 ctx.fillText("Hello",134,145);

</script>

</html>
```

Someone please clarify me the reason.

Thanks!

[image: screenshot of canvas.html]

Comment: native it seems the same to me, can you check the source code of the page and confirm that they are 100% identical?

Comment: yes they are 100% identical. This is my code. You can check it on your local server.

Comment: Do you have a doctype or html, head or /body tag? Maybe its missing the doctype in the php file.

Comment: hey yeah i tried all that. html and head tags missing here but i have it in my original code.

Comment: it will be better if you check once on your local server.

Comment: I set up a two test pages with your code: https://sotest.arcturus.uberspace.de/canvas.html, https://sotest.arcturus.uberspace.de/canvas.php — both look exactly the same (I checked in Chrome and Firefox). Could you provide further information? The complete HTTP request and the server's response would be helpful (both including the header). Also, in which browser are you experiencing this issue?